# How to mount other rack apps, such as Grape API's to Padrino application?

Tags: ruby, api, rack, padrino

I am looking around on how to mount other rack apps such as a grape API to my padrino application. I tried searching around but couldn't possibly find an answer.

I tried with the following way:

```
Padrino.mount("API", :app_file => "path_to_api_rb", :app_class => "MyApp::API").to("/")
```

But Padrino didn't start with this setting. It seems that facility is only for Padrino-sub apps. Has anyone tried this before?

Answer (score 2):

here's a project showing how to use Grape as a subapp:
[PadrinoEatsGrape](https://github.com/eivan/PadrinoEatsGrape)

(Other Rack apps could work, i guess)

Comment: Interesting, I'll try that out and see how that turns out.

Comment: I can't get this working. I've followed the file structure of this Gem but i'm getting errors, precisely: undefined method `error_format' for APIS::Vendors::Global::API_v1:Class in the console. The post is old, but if somebody have any idea is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

u can use the Rack::Cascade: to mix the grape, rails and pandrino apps:

```
rails_app = Rack::Builder.new do
  use Rails::Rack::LogTailer #Optional
  use rails::Rack::Static    #Optional
  run ActionController::Dispatcher.new
end

run Rack::Cascade.new([
  MyApp::API,
  rails_app,
  Padrino.application
])
```